# JSON in nodejs without restarting the server

Tags: node.js, json

I am using a JSON file in my node server, Which will be updated based on a cronjob. I can't get the updated data without restarting the server from the JSON. Is it possible to get the updated JSON without restarting the server>

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid having to deal with the cache of the require/import function, I think you should prefer the use of the `fs.readFile` function:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

const PATH_OF_JSON = 'data/my_json.json';

app.get('/data', async (req, res) => {
  res.send(JSON.parse(await fs.promises.readFile(PATH_OF_JSON, 'utf-8)));
});
```

Bonus: it won't use memory until you need it.